# JQuery getting width and height of next image element

Tags: jquery

I am not much into JQuery background, so it's a little difficult to make a simple thing work.

I have my HTML element as:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="box mosaic-block bar">
        <img src="images/products-mansonary/img1.jpg" />
        <div class="overlay_brand"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="images/products-mansonary/img2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="images/products-mansonary/img3.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to loop this div with id content, and get the height and width of the images:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').children('.box').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
        var img_height = $(this).next("img").height();
        var img_width = $(this).next("img").width();
        //console.log($(this).children().width());
        //console.log(img_height + "    " + img_width)
        console.log($($(this).next('img').html()));
        return false;
    });

    //$(".overlay_brand")
});
```

For the time being, I am returning false to run the loop just once.

When I say `console.log($(this).html())` I get :

```
<img src="http://localhost:5643/Template/images/products-mansonary/img1.jpg"><div class="overlay_brand"></div>
```

I hope I am not doing something silly.

Comment: Your code seems fine. What is the secific problem here?

Comment: I am getting the value as null :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try find() instead of next()

```
$('#content').children('.box').each(function() {
       console.log($(this).html());
       var img_height = $(this).find("img").height();
       var img_width = $(this).find("img").width();

       alert(img_height + "    " + img_width)


    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBkLe/1/)

Comment: Tried that too... It returns me..
0 0
0 0
0 0

Basically, still returns me 0. Is it because of dom loading.. or anything??

Comment: Your solution worked fine after i used .dotimeout/settimeout. As i am using knockout templates, it was taking time to load.. :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove the return false from the function

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#content').children('.box').each(function() {
    var img_height = $(this).find("img").height();
    var img_width = $(this).find("img").width();
    console.log("Image height "+img_height + " image width= " + img_width);    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the img within your div tag (of that specific class) use find (to look within children) and not next (to look within siblings).

```
var img_height = $(this).find("img").height();
var img_width = $(this).find("img").width();
//console.log($(this).children().width());
//console.log(img_height + "    " + img_width)
console.log($($(this).find('img').html()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting `'null'` is because `'img'` is a child of `'this'` you need to do `$(this).children("img").width();`